# La Complacencia - Pleasure or Complacency?

Tags: rae, false-friend

So I was looking up the word: "Complacencia" and I can't decide if it means "complacency" or if it's a False Friend meaning "Pleasure"

The [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/complacencia?m=form) only lists the definition as: `Satisfacción, placer y contento que resulta de algo.`

It says nothing that would be similar to the word "Complacency", which is [defined as](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/complacency): `a feeling of quiet pleasure or security, often while unaware of some potential danger`

However, I'm seeing sentences online that seem to use both definitions. So I would like to ask native speakers here: Is this a common word? and would you characterize it as a "false friend" or not?

Comment: I think the main difference is that *complacency* implies a sense of false security but «complacencia» does not.

Comment: It is a false friend.

Answer (score 1):

Potencialmente sean falsos amigos. La etimología de ambos términos es la misma y el sentimiento representado es casi el mismo pero hay dos diferencias fundamentales:

- *Complacency* pone el énfasis en el sentimiento, mientras que *complacencia* deriva de la acción de *complacer*, que por lo general es entre dos sujetos. Por lo tanto es más común pensar que 'A complace a B' en vez de que 'A se auto-complace'.
- Lo que estás indicando en tu misma pregunta: en inglés el uso de tal palabra presupone por lo general la ausencia de un 'curarse-de', mientras que  en español el término sólo se usa para el estado propiamente dicho sin que por ello deba inferirse nada a priori.

**ANEXO**

En efecto, las traducciones más apropiadas son:

- **Complacencia (acción y efecto de complacer)**: to delight sb
- **Complacencia (sentimiento que deriva de haber sido complacido)**: satisfaction or pleasure
- **Complacency:** estar anestesiado (figurativo)